# Form in a web site in the aim to update or add members

Tags: xml, odoo

I would like to create an HTML page with a form that can update a member or a member. I create the form, the link between the field and my input, what i have to add in the aim to update or add a member ?

```
<form action="" class="oe_signup_form" role="form" method="post" t-attf-action="" t-if="not message"
onsubmit="" enctype="">

<div class="form-group">

<label for="name" class="control-label">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" t-att-value="name" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" required="required"/>
Name 
</label>
</div>

<div class="clearfix oe_login_buttons">

<a t-attf-href="" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Valider</a>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Valider</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Update a member in what?! You need to show some backend for what is handling this post request?

Comment: Be clear in your explanation and add a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add record to odoo model using html form, as i understand.

First step is to make html page form.

Second step is to create web controller which will handle post request from your form

Third step using request.registry[].create() to add record to the model

Fore more detailed examples read odoo source code